# Can not access helper method methods inside asp.net mvc WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have defined this helper method inside my asp.net mvc model class:

```
public partial class Skill
{
  public int Level0Count()
  {
    return SkillLevelStaffs.Where(a => a.Level.Name.Contains("0")).Count();
  }
```

but when i try to access the Level0count() extension method inside my WebGrid as follow:

```
gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
{
  ColumnName ="Level 0",
  CanSort=false,
  Format= @<text><a data-modal='' href="/skill/GetSkillUsers......>@(item.Level0Count()) Staff/s.</a></text>
});
```

I got the following exception:

> 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'Level0Count'

Can anyone advise how i can access extension methods inside asp.net mvc webGrid?

**EDIT**

i can access the item as follow without any problems:-

```
 var gridcolumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
        gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName = "Name", Header = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().Name).ToString(),CanSort=true });
        gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
        {
            ColumnName = "Customer",
            CanSort = false,
            Format =             
                 @<text>
            @if (item.IsAllCustomer)
            {<span>All</span>}
            else
            {
                foreach (var c in ((IEnumerable<SkillManagementTDMGroup.Models.Customer>)item.Customers).OrderByDescending(a=>a.Name))
                {
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span> @(c.Name)<br />
                }
            }            

                   </text>});

  var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: true,
                        rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                        canSort: true,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
```

**EDIT 2**

here is the model i am passing to the grid:-

```
 public class PagedList<T>
    {
        public List<T> Content { get; set; }

        public Int32 CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public Int32 PageSize { get; set; }
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
        public bool OnlyActive { get; set; }
        public int? masterDetail { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages
        {
            get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalRecords / PageSize); }
        }
    }
```

and here is some of the grid columns definitions where i can access the item:-

```
var gridcolumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName = "Name", Header = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().Name).ToString(),CanSort=true });
gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = "Customer",
                CanSort = false,
                Format =             
                     @<text>
                @if (item.IsAllCustomer)
                {<span>All</span>}
                else
                {
                    foreach (var c in ((IEnumerable<SkillManagementTDMGroup.Models.Customer>)item.Customers).OrderByDescending(a=>a.Name))
                    {
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span> @(c.Name)<br />
                    }
                }            

                       </text>});
            if (Model.masterDetail.HasValue)
            {
                gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
                {
                    ColumnName = "Staff Level",
                    CanSort = false,
                    Format =

                  @<text>
              //code goes here
    gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName ="Description",Header = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().Description).ToString(),CanSort=true});



    gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName ="Level 0",CanSort=false,Format=

                  @<text>
    <a data-modal='' href="/skill/GetSkillUsers/@(item.SkillID)?levelID=@allLevels.SingleOrDefault(a2=>a2.Name.Contains("0")).LevelID"  id= "@item.SkillID" title='GetListUser'>   
     @(item.Level0Count()) Staff/s.</a>    
                </text>});
    //code goes here
                var grid = new WebGrid(
                            canPage: true,
                            rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                            canSort: true,
                            ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

                grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
                grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

                @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
                fillEmptyRows: false,
                tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                columns: gridcolumns
```

Comment: That's not an extension method: a) it's not static; b) it's not in a static class; c) it doesn't have a first parameter with the `this` modifier. It's just a normal method in the `Skill` class. Note the error says it's looking in `WebGridRow`, not `Skill`... perhaps you need to change how `item` is declared?

Comment: @JonSkeet  sorry i mean a helper method not a extension method,, but still regardless of the name i am unable to access it  inside the grid, while i can access it inside normal view..

Comment: What the heck *IS* item?  You've neglected to show it's declaration.  Look at the error message, it seems to be saying that item's type is WebGridRow, not Skill.

Comment: item is used inside the grid to access each grid row... so example i can write item.Name ,, so i will get the name of the model items

Comment: That doesn't answer the question

Comment: Well a grid row isn't a `Skill`, is it - so how did you expect this method to be found? Where *do* you have a value of type `Skill`?

Comment: i can access the skill properties using the item without any problem,, i edit my question with a sample of how i can access the item inside the WebGrid,,

Comment: @JonSkeet i am passing the skill inside the Model.content as follow :- grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);

Comment: You are still failing to include the declaration of item in your examples... the part that is the most important.  Why do you keep doing this?

Comment: That doesn't really tell us much, I'm afraid. Is that a single skill, or some list of skills, for example? It would be much easier to help you if you'd provide all the relevant context *in the question*.

Comment: @JonSkeet please find my Edit2 section with full code

Comment: You are *STILL* not including the declaration of item... the single most important part of your question.. the one thing where the error is occurring... you refuse to include this one simple piece of information that would vastly help you getting an answer, yet stubbornly refuse to provide... why?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch i am not refusing to provide,, but "item" is a reserve syntax used inside WebGrid to access individual item,, for example if i write item.Name it will show the name for the such as Model.Content.Single(a=>a.Name) ,, so i did not declare "item" it is used to access the webgrid items,, as you can see from the example i am checking (item.IsAllCustomer) and this allow me to access a model property named IsAllcustomer for each of the grid items.. hope this explain what i mean.thanks

Comment: No, that's not true.  item is not any kind of reserved name, not in the way you are referencing it.  item is declared somewhere.  right click on it and choose "go to declaration"

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch if i right click on the item and i chose "Go to definition" i will get "Can not navigate to item". also if you check this link http://www.dotnetcodesg.com/Article/UploadFile/2/286/CRUD%20operation%20using%20Modal%20Popup%20in%20ASP.NET%20MVC%204.aspx you can see that they use something such as "Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "ViewEmployeeDetail", new { id = item.id }, new { class = "viewDialog" })</text>" and they get the item.name without having to declare the item any where,,, can u adivce ?

Comment: Ok, I see how that is working based on the example you've shown.  That's a very strange way to invoke a delegate.  Regardless, you aren't showing us the complete context of the code that does NOT work, you keep showing us code that DOES work.  We need to see the entire block, including how you're binding it to your WebGrid as I suspect you may not be passing the model to the grid.

Comment: By the way, as a point.. this is not a reserved word, but it is interesting.. here is a blog article that discusses the subject.  They're called Templated Razor Delegates http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch regardless of the name seems that i can not access them inside the WebGrid, is this correct ?

Comment: @johnG - and again, you aren't showing us the complete code that does NOT work, you are only showing us the code that does... you are only showing us the one column, we need to see your entire grid code that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

For **Extension Method** the class in which method is should be **static** and that method should also be static and it's first parameter is `this Type type` so that it can be called on members of that **Type** for which we are adding Extension Method:

```
public static class Skill 
{ 
    public static int Level0Count(this WebGridRow webGridRow)
    {
         // extension method code here
        return SkillLevelStaffs.Where(a => a.Level.Name.Contains("0")).Count();
    }
}
```

See [this MSDN article for understanding of Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: sorry  i mean helper method not extension method. But still when i try to access it inside the WebGrid i will get an error. However if i try accessing it inside normal view I will get the returned int correctly by eimply writting (  @Model.Level0Count()) ? can you adivce ?

Comment: the error as i mentioned before is "

    'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'Level0Count'
"

Comment: you have to include that namspace in your view in which we have created static class

Comment: i am a bit confused now i am passing to the view "@model SkillManagement.Models.PagedList < SkillManagement.Models.Skill >" . and the PagedList have "public class PagedList<T>
    {
        public List<T> Content { get; set; }"
. so the Content is a model class and the helper method is inside the model class ,,, and as i have said if i access the helper method on the Details view for example it will work well...